# how to keep unique identifiers in a regression dataset?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

The question is simple. I have a dataset with a series of columns. One is the dependent variable and others are independent variables and some are just unique identifiers like lat,long coordinates.

I want to run a regression but make sure that I have a way to match the unique identifiers back to their respective rows and not cut out these columns. I also do not want to run the regression on the columns with the unique identifiers. How should I go about this?

Comment: see `?\`[.data.frame\``, `?match`, and `?duplicated`

Comment: You should use `augment()` from the `broom` package. It allows you to apply the model to the original data (and of course predict on new data), so the IDs and other variables not related with the model are not affected.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What are you trying to match back with your refression? Fitted values? Regression coeficients?

Comment: @AdamQuek I want to be able to do things like run a regression and make a correlation matrix but the non-numeric and non-int columns will cause errors. Eventually after running these functions as well as an RMSE, MAE etc, I'll want to have the unique identifiers in the dataset for later analysis.